# Sleep mode in WiFi

Tags: ieee-802.11

I've been looking around but I can't seem to find out if power management schemes exist only in 802.11n or in other schemes such as 802.11ac or 802.11af as well.

Could anyone point me to a good reference? I've even gone through the IEEE standards themselves, but still can't seem to be sure of this. Here is the link to the IEEE references: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxUolX14t897NktqSXNJa3JHVXM

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I can say that on the client side, power management exists down to 802.11b/g (at least with current firmware). I've seen this get enabled on wireless scan guns from [unnamed MFR] via firmware updates. Whether or not it adheres to the IEE standard, well that is another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs on your link are just the amendments. You can get the complete standard at [IEEE 802.org](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/). As far as I can see, power management from Clause 6 applies to all PHY types.

Comment: > As far as I can see, power management from Clause 6 applies to all PHY types.                     Where can I find information that proves the same? I tried looking at documents in the link that you mentioned, but can't still find a definitive answer.

Comment: Clauses 6.3.2  and 11.2 define power management. There's no mention of it being optional so I'd say it's mandatory to implement power management messaging. Whether a device actually supports various power states is probably up to the manufacturer/firmware.